How to write CSV data directly from string (or bytes) to a duckdb database file in Python?
I would like to write CSV data directly from a bytes (or string) object in memory to duckdb database file (i.e. I want to avoid having to write and read the temporary .csv files). This is what I've got so far:
import io 
import duckdb 

data = b'a,b,c\n0,1,2\n3,4,5'
rawtbl = duckdb.read_csv(
    io.BytesIO(data), header=True, sep=","
)

con = duckdb.connect('some.db')
con.sql('CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT * FROM rawtbl')

which throws following exception:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOException                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 10
      5 rawtbl = duckdb.read_csv(
      6     io.BytesIO(data), header=True, sep=","
      7 )
      9 con = duckdb.connect('some.db')
---> 10 con.sql('CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT * FROM rawtbl')

IOException: IO Error: No files found that match the pattern "DUCKDB_INTERNAL_OBJECTSTORE://2843be5a66472f9c"

However, it is possible to do:
>>> duckdb.sql('CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT * FROM rawtbl')
>>> duckdb.sql('show tables')
┌─────────┐
│  name   │
│ varchar │
├─────────┤
│ foo     │
└─────────┘
>>> duckdb.sql('SELECT * from foo')
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│   a   │   b   │   c   │
│ int64 │ int64 │ int64 │
├───────┼───────┼───────┤
│     0 │     1 │     2 │
│     3 │     4 │     5 │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘


since rawtbl is a duckdb.duckdb.DuckDBPyRelation object. But that is the in-memory duckdb database, not the 'some.db' file.
Question
How to read csv data directly from bytes (or a string) to duckdb database file, without using intermediate CSV files?
Versions
duckdb 0.10.2 on Python 3.12.2 on Ubuntu

You can create the connection before you use read_csv and pass the connection into it.
import io
import duckdb
from pathlib import Path


data = b'a,b,c\n0,1,2\n3,4,5'
db_path = 'some.db'
Path(db_path).unlink(missing_ok=True)

with duckdb.connect(db_path) as con:
    rawtbl = duckdb.read_csv(
        io.BytesIO(data), header=True, sep=",", connection=con,
    )

    con.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE foo as select * from rawtbl
    ''')

with duckdb.connect(db_path) as con:
    res = con.sql('select * from foo')
    print(res)

# ┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
# │   a   │   b   │   c   │
# │ int64 │ int64 │ int64 │
# ├───────┼───────┼───────┤
# │     0 │     1 │     2 │
# │     3 │     4 │     5 │
# └───────┴───────┴───────┘


Thanks! Did'nt realize that the duckdb.read_csv() takes a connection argument! Also noticed that you may use con.read_csv() directly.

I'm not entirely sure on best practices, but I did manage to get it to work with ATTACH.
duckdb.sql("attach 'some.db'")

duckdb_databases() gave me the names.
duckdb.sql("from duckdb_databases()")

┌───────────────┬──────────────┬─────────┬───┬──────────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ database_name │ database_oid │  path   │ … │ internal │  type   │ readonly │
│    varchar    │    int64     │ varchar │   │ boolean  │ varchar │ boolean  │
├───────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┼───┼──────────┼─────────┼──────────┤
│ memory        │         1080 │ NULL    │ … │ false    │ duckdb  │ false    │
│ some          │         1489 │ some.db │ … │ false    │ duckdb  │ false    │
│ system        │            0 │ NULL    │ … │ true     │ duckdb  │ false    │
│ temp          │         1479 │ NULL    │ … │ true     │ duckdb  │ false    │
├───────────────┴──────────────┴─────────┴───┴──────────┴─────────┴──────────┤
│ 4 rows                                                 7 columns (6 shown) │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

We can then USE the file-backed db and select the data from rawtbl.
duckdb.sql("""
use "some";
create table foo as (from rawtbl)
""")

Check the result:
con = duckdb.connect("some.db")
con.sql("from foo")

┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│   a   │   b   │   c   │
│ int64 │ int64 │ int64 │
├───────┼───────┼───────┤
│     0 │     1 │     2 │
│     3 │     4 │     5 │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘

